# Launch "select file" dialog using a shell script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, is it possible to launch a "select file" dialog from the command line? I need to find a command that launches the "select file" dialog (so that I can prompt the user to navigate to a file using a shell script, and then return the file path.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `zenity`

More reference here: http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/file-selection.html.en

Comment: Specifically, `zenity --file-selection` will prompt the user to click on a file, and then it will print the file path. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: For my M.tech project, The entire user interface (whatever minimal) on PC side was done with zenity command line! :-) You may like to have a look at other options as well. It's a good tool for creating simple GUI.

Comment: why use zenity at all if we are not using it for anything else? Cannot we call the default file manager's selection dialog? I recall having used it but cant find it anywhere now :(

Comment: @shubham, We developers are used to terminal or curses based menu. Many people prefer a mouse. TBH, I think it also depends on your use case. If your application is terminal-based and you need a file browsing dialog, I'd use curses-based solution. If they want to select something by clicking a .desktop file, I would choose zenity. One of my implementation also used a mixed solution by detecting an interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

I use [kdialog](https://develop.kde.org/deploy/kdialog/):

```
kdialog --getopenfilename . 'audio/ogg audio/mp3 audio/wav'
kdialog --getsavefilename . 'audio/ogg audio/mp3 audio/wav'
```

To open multiple files:

```
variable=$(kdialog --getopenfilename --multiple . 'audio/ogg audio/mp3 audio/wav');
variable=$(echo $variable | sed 's/\ \//\\n\//g')
```