# How to select the native GUI backend for standard Tkinter input dialogs on Python

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, backend

This Python 3.11 script on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Open file', filetypes=(("BMP files", "*.bmp"), ("All files", "*")))
```

opens this dialog box:

[image]

It looks different from the native file dialog, for example the one from GIMP:

[image]

Is there away to select the latter to be used with `askopenfilename()`?

Comment: There is no way afaik. 1 possible option is to see what the file dialog is and try running it using python's `subprocess` module but that is platform dependant.

Comment: There is no built-in way to alter the appearance of the [open file dialog box](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/getOpenFile.html). The dialog boxes are for convenience, so you won't have to design your own. However, you are able to do so with tcl/tk or tkinter and python. A different approach might be using a [bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13410902/13629335)